# connected bluetooth devices don't output audio on macbook air

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I have a pair of wireless headphones, and airpods that i can connect to my macbook air via bluetooth. However moments after connecting and attempting to play some audio they disconnect and the audio plays via the internal speakers. The headphones and airpods work fine with my phone, I have tried to forget both of them on my phone and then tried to reconnect with my macbook but it didn't work. Using macOS high sierra btw.